# Android: how to avoid blink effect when clicking a webView item

Tags: android, webview

I have a jqplot chart inside a webView in Android app; when the user clicks the chart there is a "flash" effect and all the chart becomes selected.
Is there a way to avoid this effect?

Comment: i've used this JS http://cubiq.org/remove-onclick-delay-on-webkit-for-iphone to get rid of the delay when clicking in Android browser - I'd imagine it'd suppress the effect you're describing as well, as the default behavior is prevented (I realize the page says for iPhone, but I have used it with Android browser)

Comment: try this link: [How to Hide Android WebView Highlight Border (or change it’s color)](http://danbarnett.net/how-to-hide-android-webview-highlight-border-or-change-its-color-142.html)